# Network is unreachable after doing ping

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, virtualbox, internet

I have set up ubuntu server through oracle virtual box Now whenever the ubuntu server start & ask for username password & when i ping any website or ip address its `unknown host` or `network is unreachable`

In my Indows pc Internet is working totally fine & at the bootom of virtualbox there is a icon saying connected to bridge adapter

Whenever i write ifconfig no ip is listed

here is what i get after ifconfig

```
enpOs3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:b8:fb:44  
          inet6 addr: fe80::27ff:fe8b:fb44/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (8.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1708 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1708 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:126308 (126.3 KB)  TX bytes:126308 (126.3 KB)

root@darkstar:~# ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem
In network Setting>Advance>Choose PCNET FAST III as adapter type
& it started working